# Why is there a clicking sound at the beginning and end of sounds produced by my echo program?

Tags: c, audio, wav

I have a program that creates an echo from a sound file and amplitude and delay (in samples) and writes it to a file. The problem is that at the beginning and end of the echo, there is a clicking noise. I don't know how to fix it.

The program adds the original sound wave data with the delayed sound wave data. This is done under the assumption that the number of channels is always 2. The left and right channel is always present. The sound files I tested the program with have 2 channels. The sound files are always WAV files.

The program is supposed to be started like this:
./render_echo {input file name} {output file name} {delay in samples} {amplitude}

Example:
./render_echo sound1.wav sound2.wav 22050 0.4
For an echo with half second delay assuming sample rate is 44100.

Echo program:

```c
int check_args(char* inputFile, char* outputFile, int delay, float amplitude){

  if (inputFile == NULL){
    printf("Error: improper input file name\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (outputFile == NULL){
    printf("Error: improper output file name\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (delay < 0){
    printf("Error: delay cannot be negative\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (amplitude <= 0.0 || amplitude > 1.0){
    printf("Error: amplitude must be between 0 and 1, exclusive.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}



int main(int argc, char** argv){

  //Check if the number of arguments equals 5
  if (argc != 5){
    printf("Error: wrong number of arguments");
    return 1;
  }

  //Make sure arguments are correct
  char* inputFileName = argv[1];
  char* outputFileName = argv[2];
  float amplitude = atof(argv[4]);

  if (check_args(inputFileName, outputFileName, atof(argv[3]), amplitude) == 1){
    return 1;
  }

  //Delay is expressed in number of samples
  unsigned monodelay = atof(argv[3]);
  unsigned delay = monodelay*2;


  //printf("amp %f\n", amplitude);

  FILE *inputFile = fopen(inputFileName, "rb");
  if (inputFile == NULL){
    printf("Error: couldn't read file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  //Read wave header
  unsigned num_samples_input_monochannel;
  read_wave_header(inputFile, &num_samples_input_monochannel);
  unsigned num_samples_input = 2*num_samples_input_monochannel;
  //printf("Mono %u Dual %u\n", num_samples_input_monochannel, num_samples_input);

  //Read wave data
  int16_t input_wave[num_samples_input];
  read_s16_buf(inputFile, input_wave, num_samples_input);

  //New output file info
  unsigned num_samples_output_monochannel = num_samples_input_monochannel + monodelay;
  unsigned num_samples_output = num_samples_output_monochannel*2;
  int16_t output_wave[num_samples_output];
  memset(output_wave, 0, num_samples_output);

  //New waves
  int16_t input_wave_dual[2][num_samples_output_monochannel];
  memset(input_wave_dual[0], 0, num_samples_output_monochannel);
  memset(input_wave_dual[1], 0, num_samples_output_monochannel);

  //Fill input_wave_dual
  for (int i=0; i<num_samples_input_monochannel; i++){
    input_wave_dual[0][i] = input_wave[i*2]; //left channel
    input_wave_dual[1][i] = input_wave[i*2 + 1]; //right channel
  }

  //Time delayed wave
  int16_t delayed_wave_dual[2][num_samples_output_monochannel];
  memset(delayed_wave_dual[0], 0, num_samples_output_monochannel);
  memset(delayed_wave_dual[1], 0, num_samples_output_monochannel);

  //Fill time delayed wave
  for (int j=0; j<num_samples_output_monochannel;j++){
    delayed_wave_dual[0][monodelay+j-1] = input_wave_dual[0][j]*amplitude;
    delayed_wave_dual[1][monodelay+j-1] = input_wave_dual[1][j]*amplitude;
  }

  //Add the two waves
  for (int k=0; k<num_samples_output_monochannel; k++){
    for (int l=0; l<2;l++){
      //Temp input amplitude
      int temp_i_a = input_wave_dual[l][k];
      //Temp delay amplitude
      int temp_d_a = delayed_wave_dual[l][k];
      //Temp sum
      int temp_sum = temp_i_a + temp_d_a;
      if (temp_sum > INT16_MAX){
    temp_sum = INT16_MAX;
      } else if (temp_sum < INT16_MIN){
    temp_sum = INT16_MIN;
      }

      output_wave[k*2 +l] = temp_sum;
    }
  }



  //WRITE TO FILE
  FILE *outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "wb+");
  if (outputFile == NULL){
    printf("Error: could not write file");
    return 1;
  }

  write_wave_header(outputFile, num_samples_output_monochannel);

  write_s16_buf(outputFile, output_wave, num_samples_output);

  fclose(outputFile);
  fclose(inputFile);

  printf("Finished\n");

}
```

Comment: use [atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) to convert a string to an integer (or better yet, something like [strtol](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) since it does error checking and lets you specify a base).

Comment: @yano argv[3] is the delay in samples. It cannot be negative because the delay cannot be negative. The amplitude must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: yes my mistake, was miscounting arguments.

Comment: a pop can be generated when the initial or final height of the raw audio curve is not zero ... meaning as the audio curve wobbles up and down from say +1 to -1 as it is generating audio this directly controls the output speaker physical position of the diaphragm  ... when the audio first starts this diaphragm is at rest which equates to the zero mark ...  if the audio starts at a value other than this zero there is a mismatch between the signal being sent to the speaker and the physical location of the speaker moving parts

Comment: I added a line to the code to set the amplitude of the first and last sample to 0, but the click is still there.

Comment: Well, you don't need a single 0 sample, but a raising or falling edge at a rate slow enough. Load your generated wave file into an audio editor like Audacity and look at the curve. You can compare it with the original wave file. Does the original click, too?